# Why shuffling by picking random position in all array instead of a part is not correct

Tags: algorithms, arrays, randomized-algorithms

There is a famous problem to generate a [random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) of elements in an array - it's called *shuffling*. My understanding of that problem is that I have to put every element in an array into a random position. So for each element in an array I can generate a random position and put it there by swapping:

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const position = rand.nextInt(a.length);
    const tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[position];
    a[position] = tmp;
}
```

This is almost what the improved [Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is doing. However my solution is not correct. According to the link I need to generate numbers from the `0..i` range, not from `0..length`. Can anyone please explain me why it is so?

In my implementation all the numbers are still put into random positions, so what's the problem?

Comment: It will shuffle but it will not be uniform i.e. all elements will not have an equal chance of appearing at some position 'i'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple mathematical argument that your algorithm *cannot* pick each permutation with equal probability: There are $n^n$ possibilities how your algorithm can choose random numbers, each with equal probability, and each producing some permutation. There are $n!$ possible permutations. But $n^n$ is not divisible by $n!$ if $n ≥ 3$, therefore the permutations cannot all be the result of the same number of random choices.

Yuval gave the example for n = 3: There are $3^3=27$ possible choices of random numbers, and $3! = 6$ possible permutations. $27/6 = 4.5$. It is not possible that each permutation is the result of 4.5 different choices of random numbers. As Yuval's table shows, there are three permutations each being produced by 4 and by 5 choices of random numbers, so some permutations *must* be more likely than others.

For n = 2 this argument doesn't show any problem since $2^2 = 4$ is divisible by $2! = 2$, and indeed the algorithm produces a random permutation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your elaborate answer! I find it very helpful. Yuval's answer as I understand is also very good, but it's difficult for me to understand given my limited knowledge of the topic. Can you please clarify a few things? _there are three permutations each being produced by 4 and by 5 choices of random numbers_ - what do you mean by `produced by 4 and by 5 choices`?

Comment: _therefore the permutations cannot all be the result of the same number of random choices_ - can you maybe provide an example?

Comment: any comment on my questions above?

Answer (score 9):

Suppose that the array has length $n$. Since you are making $n$ random choices of numbers from 1 to $n$, the probability to obtain any specific permutation is of the form $A/n^n$, for some integer $A$. Therefore your algorithm could work only if $n^n/n!$ is an integer, which is only the case when $n \leq 2$.

More concretely, if you shuffle the array $1,2,3$, then you get the following results:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{array} & \text{probability} \\\hline
1,2,3 & 4/27 \\
1,3,2 & 5/27 \\
2,1,3 & 5/27 \\
2,3,1 & 5/27 \\
3,1,2 & 4/27 \\
3,2,1 & 4/27 
\end{array}
$$

Comment: thanks, how do you calculate the probability `4/27` and `5/27` in your table?

Comment: @Maximus I ran all 27 possible executions of the program.

Comment: aha, and then what? I'm sorry I can seem to understand how you end up with the table results

Comment: You'll have to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are putting the numbers in random positions, although this is not the correct implementation of  Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm (if you intended to). You are basically using a slightly different algorithm such that:

If **n = a[i]** is swapped with **m = a[position]**, the algorithm can still generate **position = i** and swap **m = a[i]** with another number **a[i+1]**.
In  Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm this wouldn't happen as it would use **i+1 ... a.length-1** as possible values for **position**. So **m** wouldn't be swapped again.

EDIT: You should also check this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47338/whats-a-uniform-shuffle) and understand the concept of **uniform shuffle**.

Comment: This might help for a better understanding
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54rMYC2pEtw

Comment: This doesn't quite explain what goes wrong if you use the wrong algorithm.